# Moving a box, text etc

Tags: tables

I have searched the page for how to move a box around on a paper, but I have not found an answer.

If the left-bottom corner of the paper is at (0,0) (x, y). I have the following script:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
Reinforcement(A)&Concrete(B)&slab formwork(D)\\ \hline \\
kg & m3 & m2 \\
B-man hours & B man hours & B man-hours \\
blah blah & blah blah & blah blah \\
\end{tabular}
```

The box must start point (10cm, 10cm)

but how?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you use a 0-sized picture mode then it is easy to set the table (10,10) relative to the origin of the picture mode, it's a bit more involved to position the picture mode at the edge of the page as you have to account for the usual margins and offsets.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{1cm}


\noindent\vbox to 0pt{%
\vspace{\dimexpr \paperheight-\topskip-\topmargin-1in
-\headheight-\headsep}

\noindent\hspace*{\dimexpr-\oddsidemargin-1in}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\thicklines\linethickness{5pt}
\put(10,10){%
\begin{tabular}[b]{lrr}
Reinforcement(A)&Concrete(B)&slab formwork(D)\\ \hline \\
kg & m3 & m2 \\
B-man hours & B man hours & B man-hours \\
blah blah & blah blah & blah blah \\
\end{tabular}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){10}}
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){10}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\end{picture}
\vss}
\end{document}
```